# Tab bar controller change pointing to new view controller for existing item

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I created one tab view controller with 2 default tab bar actions and I have one view controller with different functionality and now I want to point that View controller in place of second tab bar item. How can I do this through story board?

Comment: As per my understanding, your going to use a same controller for two tab items right? if not, could you please explain the issue in detail.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) delete segue from default view controller (DEFAULT SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER)

[image]

2) Control Click from tab bar controller to your custom view controller and select Relationship segue.

[image]

3) It will assign your custom view controller as second tab

[image]

Comment: @Akshaykumar Digrase, did this answer resolved your query? if yes, please mark this as approved.